# Why is my shed floor staying damp?

Tags: subfloor, shed, moisture

I built a shed last summer at my recreational property. This winter when it was snowing, I was up in shed and the plywood floor got pretty wet. It seems to have never really dried dry out all winter. I had Thompson's Water Seal™ on it, but I don't understand why it did not dry out on its own, other then the 30° to 40° temps. This past weekend I put heater in shed to dry it out and it seemed to do the trick.

I know the temperature have not been above min forties, but I still thought it would dry out on its own. Was that to be expected?

Secondly, my floor is about 10 to 11" off the ground (to the plywood bottom) but I did not put gravel under it. The skids are on pavers and I figured with the height it would be fine. I have treated skids and floor joists. Would no gravel under the shed cause the shed floor inside to be damp or stay damp or is it just the temps never letting it dry? There is no standing water under shed.

Comment: What is the shed's ventilation arrangement?

Comment: Ecnerwal - The whole front has about 6 inches between bottom of joists to ground and the whole back has about 8 inches bottom of joists and ground. Sides only have about 2 inches. The joists sit on top of 4x4 skids & pavers, so there is open area for air flow. Inside I have a 10 x 10 vent on the upper front and upper back of shed. Other than that, it's fairly tight with seals around door, with exception of some gaps around birds nest blocks (no cutouts)

Comment: So the interior is "fairly tight," with some vents up high only? Ventilation around the outside only does so much for water on the inside. Of course, you also have to make sure it's really retained melted snow water from months ago, not just a roof leak or windblown rain through vents from every time it rains and whenever it rained most recently, which is the Occam's Razor hypothesis here.

Comment: Ecnerwal - What I mean by fairly tight is that the only airflow mean to be allowed in though the vents. I see no indication of water coming in though vents or leaking roof. No wetness anywhere except on the floor when it got wet from when used during winter one time, which is why i asked. Would that be normal to not completely dry because of 30 to 40 degree temps? My biggest question is, would no gravel under shed, with 10 to 11 inches of clearance to subfloor and open air flow cause wet floors in shed.

Comment: Small battery-powered temp/humidity sensors are fairly cheap these days. I'd buy a half dozen and place them in various areas of the shed, on floor, up high, middle etc. Then you can monitor how damp it really gets. You can even get bluetooth/wifi connected sensors for a bit more.

Comment: If the air movement inside is only up high, (rather than low to high) there's not much going on to dry the floor, air-movement-wise.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/269232/plywood-floor-coating

Comment: @Huesmann, coating the floor treats a symptom. The disease (high moisture content) is likely to result in mold and rot. It should be addressed. Plus it's already coated.

Comment: @isherwood - Agreed. Trying to find the cause but no clear evidence of what is causing it. But still going to coat floor with better coating to keep wood floor dry if it keeps happening. I still believe it was from heavy water exposure this winter when up working there. Never got a chance to completely dry out and made for humid conditions keeping floor damp

Comment: What part of the country are you in?  In many places, the air is pretty dry in the winter, so even if it's snowing, I would be surprised to see moisture condensing on a cold, outside surface.  Usually the dew point is below the temperature,  Your shed isn't heated, is it?

Comment: @SteveSh - Washington state. We have wet winters here. The moisture is on the inside of shed floor, no heat. I may have to add heat if this is going to be a problem.

Comment: Just the inside of the shed floor?  Not the walls?

Comment: @steveSh - yep just the floor. No moisture on roof sheathing, walls, shelves or anything in the shed.  I still believe it was from heavy water exposure this winter when up working there. Never got a chance to completely dry out and made for humid conditions keeping floor damp. You think that's possible?

Comment: Here's something to try.  Tape a 12"x12" piece of plastic or aluminum foil to the floor.  Make sure it's sealed good around the edges.  After a day or two, remove the plastic/foil and see what side has moisture on it.  If it's the side that's exposed to the air, then you know that's it's not moisture in the wood floor that's causing the problem.

Comment: @SteveSh - Thanks, I'm heading up on 31st and will give it a test. Thank you

Comment: @isherwood as I said, it depends on the source of the moisture.  If it's from water being tracked in, there's nothing wrong with simply covering the floor with a waterproof covering.

Comment: It already _has_ a waterproof coating, and Thompsons isn't a good base for other coatings.

Comment: @ isherwood - Good point. Except maybe a oil based paint