# What can I use as a plywood floor coating in a shed?

Tags: paint, plywood

I want to find a coating to put on my shed plywood floor to keep water from destroying the wood from rain/snow in winter since it does not seem to dry out on its own. That way I could be wiped/moped up when done using it to keep it from sitting all winter. Would like to also keep costs down.

Comment: Try marine paint. Be sure to properly prime the wood first.

Comment: If the water is from moisture being tracked in, some simple vinyl sheeting would do the trick.  If it's from precip *falling* in, you probably have a bigger issue than the floor getting wet.

Comment: Gil - What would be  good primer? Kilz?

Comment: Huesmann - Thanks I'm trying to figure out of there is moisture coming from. I don't see any indication of roof leaking. I have vents in both roof peaks and there was some mold on the wood inside one end. So, maybe I need to cover them in winter.  I am hoping it's just the water from tracking in and not being able to dry completely because of 25 t0 40 degree temps all winter. Is there any change the moisture inside on floor could be from no gravel under shed? I have paver block, 4x4 skids & 2x6 joists, so there is a good 10 to 12 inches of open area under shed for air flow & no standing water.

Comment: @Dean why not lay down some paper or cardboard and see what happens?

Comment: @Huesmann - Are you saying to lay it down inside shed or under shed on dirt? I was just thinking that laying down some Visqueen underneath would help if moisture is coming from underside. Is that what you are suggesting with cardboard?

Comment: Lay the cardboard or paper on the floor of the shed, and see where it gets wet.

Answer (score 2):

Two part epoxy resin would work great as long as the floor is solid. Any flexibility in the floor underneath could cause cracking. Use a squeegee to thin it out and keep your costs down. It can be quite slippery when wet - I sanded mine to minimize slipping.

Comment: Adding sand is appropriate for _any_ floor coating that might be wet.

Comment: Sophie, thank you for suggestion. Not much flex in floor, but sounds like it could be a maintenance nightmare. I will likely go with Marine paint that was suggested by Gil.

Comment: @freeman - are you saying to add sand to the inside on top of plywood?

Comment: @Dean any surface coating should have some sort of grit added to it for grip. Have you ever walked into a store with a tile/linoleum/vinyl floor fresh from a rainstorm? Floor is slippery as all get out. That's why they put the floor mats down - to dry your shoes so you don't die. Next time it rains, get on your bicycle and try braking on the road, now try braking on a painted line on the road - HUGE difference in grip. (Actually don't try that - you'll end up on the road with the bike above you.) Yes, you need some sort of grip on a painted/epoxy surface. (con't...)

Comment: ... Some floor coatings will come with some sort of grit already in it that will, of course, need to be thoroughly mixed to ensure it's well spread, but if you're going to use some basic house paint, you'll want to add it yourself.